# Case Hour is ~6 Hours off

Tags: apex, case, custom-field

I have a "Hour" field added to the case object. It is calculated by HOUR(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)). If a case was opened at 00:30, it was saying the hour was "6". There is a consistent 6 hour offset.

I was thinking maybe it was caused by my team being around the world but I am under the assumption SF runs on CST. Please advise how I can fix this snippet to reflect the correct date.

Comment: Datetimes are actually stored (by Salesforce) in UTC+0 (GMT), and then the appropriate offset is added based on the time zone of the user. If you're doing any processing with Apex, you need to take care to use the appropriate methods (i.e.  `hour()` vs `hourGMT()`). It should be harder to mess that up if you're only using a formula field.

Comment: I ended up resolving it with VALUE( MID( TEXT( CreatedDate - 6/24), 12, 2 ) ). I am in PST, but most of my team is IST or CST and they see it. Using this method accounted for that 6 hour offset (the 6/24 part does that if anyone needs to know, the number following UTC+ for a timezone is what you put in place of the 6)

Answer (score 0):

I pivoted to calculating the HOUR field using this function
VALUE( MID( TEXT( CreatedDate - 6/24), 12, 2 ) )